# Grep with reg ex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

Trying to use regex with grep in the command line to give me lines that start with either a whitespace or lowercase int followed by a space. From there, they must end with either a semi colon or a o.

I tried

```
grep ^[\s\|int]\s+[\;\o]$ fileName
```

but I don't get what I'm looking for. I also tried

```
grep ^\s*int\s+([a-z][a-zA-Z]*,\s*)*[a-z]A-Z]*\s*;
```

but nothing.

Comment: You should probably always put your regexes in single quotes, to prevent your shell from mucking with it before it gets to `grep`, e.g. `grep '^something.*$' fileName`.

Comment: Example string and and expected result would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
 keep marco
polo
int keep;
int x
```

If I understand your rules correctly, two of the lines in the above should be kept and the other two discarded.

Let's try `grep`:

```
$ grep -E '^(\s|int\s).*[;o]$' file
 keep marco
int keep;
```

The above uses `\s` to mean space.  `\s` is supported by GNU grep.  For other greps, we can use a POSIX character class instead.  After reorganizing the code slightly to reduce typing:

```
grep -E '^(|int)[[:blank:]].*[;o]$' file
```

#### How it works

In a Unix shell, the single quotes in the command are critical: they stop the shell from interpreting or expanding any character inside the single quotes.

`-E` tells grep to use extended regular expressions.  Thus reduces the need for backslashes.

Let's examine the regular expression, one piece at a time:

1. `^` matches at the beginning of a line.
2. `(\s|int\s)`  This matches *either* a space *or* `int` followed by a space.
3. `.*` matches zero or more of any character.
4. `[;o]`  matches any character in the square brackets which means that it matches either `;` or `o`.
5. `$` matches at the end of a line.